# Html Post Method get blank page after refresh

Tags: php, html

I am testing Html form using post method and got this odd result:
I have two html pages on **server apache** (already installed php): post.html and target.html, and the code for these page are followings:

**post.html** (don't worry about the html standard)

```
    <div style="text-align: center">
       <form method="POST" action="target.html">
          <input type="text" name="testname" value="sometext" />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

and **target.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Target page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I entered data to the form on post.html page and hit submit button, I got to the target.html page. When on this page(target.html), I refreshed the page, and what I receive is a blank page. The second time I refreshed, It turned to normal Html page.

I don't know why it returned a blank page the first time I refreshed, I have tried the same approach but with PHP page, and the content of target page (assum name target.php) still remains (not blank like html files above)
So, could you explain me about this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: is that the  exact code you used.?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? what's the usecase? And the action must be a `.php` page, and I don't see you are using the post data anywhere in `target.php`

Comment: Try `<form method="GET"`. (assuming you will parse the url using javascript) i don't think there is other way to get what you post into html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely has something to do with your browser. Same here on a mac using Safari, on some pages after submitting the content, the page seems to freeze, I refresh it, and then it works again.

Definitely not a code problem, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: So I found an resonable explaination from your answer, It's a browser behaviour. This happens on chrome, but not with firefox or IE. Thank think123!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you cannot pass an input from html to html file. Your target.html should be a php  file (target.php).
and try to put this code on your target.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST); //this will show the inputted text and also show the data type and will stop the code execution here. other codes below will not be executed.
echo $_POST['testname'];
?>
```

Additionally, change target.html to target.php in your form action

Answer (score 0):

First I will start out by correcting your post.html

```
<div style="text-align: center;"> <!-- added a ; after center -->
   <form method="POST" action="target.html">
      <input type="text" name="testname" value="sometext" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

that may not matter but you should end all your styles with ;

To continue, everything looks fine. maybe something weird happened between refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

save your form page in php than add the php script in the same page, here try this. remember save in .php.

```
<?php $testname = $_Post['testname'];
echo $testname ?>


<div style="text-align: center">
       <form method="POST" action="">
          <input type="text" name="testname" value="sometext" />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```